# How to create text span over few columns of a table?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to span column text over 3 columns of a grid (table).
It should start at 3rd column and wrap at the end of 5th column.

I managed to do the span just by adding a css style to 3rd column's class - overflow: visible

But now I need to limit this span at the end of 5th column and to wrap text over there.

I don't have an option to modify the table's html in order to include another table within or col-span property. The grid is dynamic. Is it possible to achieve it with some JavaScript and css?

Comment: Please refer to the documentation for [mcve].  You're asking us how to fix an issue with logic, without showing us the logic you've made.

Comment: The `colspan` attribute of the `<td>` element is built for just that purpose . . . you can find more information on it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td

Answer (score 1):

use colspan

```
<table>
 <caption>Life Expectancy By Current Age</caption>
 <tr>
  <th colspan="2">65</th>
  <th colspan="2">40</th> 
  <th colspan="2">20</th> 
 </tr> 
 <tr> 
   <th>Men</th> 
   <th>Women</th> 
   <th>Men</th> 
   <th>Women</th> 
   <th>Men</th> 
   <th>Women</th> 
 </tr> 
 <tr> 
   <td>82</td> 
   <td>85</td> 
   <td>78</td> 
   <td>82</td> 
   <td>77</td> 
   <td>81</td> 
 </tr> 
</table>
```

Read more: https://html.com/tables/rowspan-colspan/#ixzz5oaCH7Owk

Answer (score 0):

Use the column-span css property in your element. Do style="column-span: 2;". That will assure you it will only take 2 columns, which should start from your 3rd column (because you already set that up) and end on your 5th.

You can read more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css3_pr_column-span.asp

NOTE: If you're doing it inside a table, it is better to use colspan like it's shown in the example below. Both work, but colspan has better browser support and is specifically designed for tables.
UPDATE:

```
       <tr>
           <td>
               this is a normal column
           </td>
           <td colspan="2">
               this is the column taking from 3th to 5th columns
           </td>
           <td>
               this is a normal column
           </td>
       </tr>
```

Comment: show some example to understand

Comment: @ArindamSarkar there it is, please check.

Comment: This is a classic "way too fast on the answer button" answer. `column-span` is only for multi-column layouts, not tables, so that makes no sense. `colspan` is correct, but asking for actual code in an answer is not the way to go; that's a good use of comments (for clarification). Also, if you're going to show an example, at least show another row with more columns, to demonstrate the spanning of columns.

Comment: I asked for code to demonstrate how my example would work in there. I didn't need it for my answer. It would help to make sure that's what he need tho.